ggiraph tooltip showing same values at all points in geom_line_interactive()
I am trying to use geom_line_interactive() in library(ggiraph) in R to create an interactive line plot. The plot renders fine and the tooltip appears, but it shows the same values at all points on the line. (Everywhere says Year: 2013, Pre-Foreclosure Notices Issues: 69,840. This is the correct value for 2013, but it shows for each year in 2014-2023 as well.)
I think this question is slightly different from this post. I am trying to understand why geom_line_interactive doesn't change hover text.
I tried to use the same structure as when I used ggiraph to create interactive bar graphs. In those, the tooltip shows up correctly at all spots - this is the only thing I need to change.
The code I'm running is below, and below that I've added code that achieves my end goal but does so without reconciling the issue with geom_line_interactive(). Really appreciate any insight!
#data
dput(data.frame(
  year = c(2011:2023),
  fc_geo_type = rep("city", 13),
  fc_geoid = rep(606, 13),
  pfn_fam14condo = c(79541, 77001, 69840, 43282, 36689, 38794, 50016, 48553, 42167, 23698, 17802, 38729, NA)
)
)

#adding library
library(ggiraph)

### Interactive Figure
pfn_fig_ggiraph <- pfn_city %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = year, 
      y = pfn_fam14condo,
      group = fc_geoid,  
      tooltip = paste0(
        "Year: ",year,"\n",
        "Pre-Foreclosure Notices Issued: ",scales::comma(pfn_fam14condo, accuracy = 1
                                                         )
        )
      )
    ) +
  geom_line_interactive(
    stat = "identity", #is this needed? 
    linewidth = 1, 
    color = temp_fc_pal$cat1[[1]]
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = {soc_year - 10}:soc_year,
    limits = c({soc_year - 10},soc_year)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::comma_format(accuracy = 1), 
    limits = c(0, 80000),
    breaks = seq(0, 80000, 10000)
  ) + 
  labs(
    title = title,
    x = NULL,
    y = NULL,
    fill = NULL,
    caption = caption
  ) +
  fcthemes::theme_fc_base(base_size = 40) + 
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(lineheight = 0.3),
    plot.caption = element_text(lineheight = 0.3),
    legend.margin = margin(10,0,10,0)
  )


pfn_fig_ggiraph_int <- girafe(
  ggobj = pfn_fig_ggiraph, 
  width = 10, 
  height = 6,
  options = list(
    opts_hover(css = "fill:#6f1d1b;"),
    opts_hover_inv(css = "opacity:0.3;"),
    opts_selection(type = "multiple", css = "fill:#FF851B;stroke:black;"),
    opts_toolbar(
      saveaspng = FALSE,
      position = "topright",
      delay_mouseout = 10000),
    opts_tooltip(
       css = "
       background-color:white;
       color:black;
       padding:5px;
       border-radius:5px;
       font-family:National;
       font-size:20px;",#
      #opacity = 0.9,
      use_fill = FALSE
      ),
    opts_sizing(rescale = TRUE),
    opts_zoom(max = 2)
  ))

pfn_fig_ggiraph_int
  
#saving the file
htmltools::save_html(pfn_fig_ggiraph_int, file.path(out_dir_int_tests, "pfn_fig_ggiraph.html"))

If I run the following, I create something that works perfectly fine, but I'm hoping understand what I'm doing wrong with geom_line_interactive.
#adding library
library(ggiraph)

### Interactive Figure
pfn_fig_ggiraph <- pfn_city %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = year, 
      y = pfn_fam14condo,
      group = fc_geoid, #needed to make the line show 
      tooltip = paste0(
        "Year: ",year,"\n",
        "Pre-Foreclosure Notices Issued: ",scales::comma(pfn_fam14condo, accuracy = 1
                                                         )
        )
      )
    ) +
  geom_line(
    stat = "identity", #is this needed? 
    linewidth = 1, 
    color = temp_fc_pal$cat1[[1]]
  )+ 
  geom_point_interactive(
    stat = "identity", #is this needed? 
    color = temp_fc_pal$cat1[[1]]
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = {soc_year - 10}:soc_year,
    limits = c({soc_year - 10},soc_year)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::comma_format(accuracy = 1), 
    limits = c(0, 80000),
    breaks = seq(0, 80000, 10000)
  ) + 
  labs(
    title = title,
    x = NULL,
    y = NULL,
    fill = NULL,
    caption = caption
  ) +
  fcthemes::theme_fc_base(base_size = 40) + 
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(lineheight = 0.3),
    plot.caption = element_text(lineheight = 0.3),
    legend.margin = margin(10,0,10,0)
  )


pfn_fig_ggiraph_int <- girafe(
  ggobj = pfn_fig_ggiraph, 
  width = 10, 
  height = 6,
  options = list(
    opts_hover(css = "fill:#6f1d1b;"),
    opts_hover_inv(css = "opacity:0.3;"),
    opts_selection(type = "multiple", css = "fill:#FF851B;stroke:black;"),
    opts_toolbar(
      saveaspng = FALSE,
      position = "topright",
      delay_mouseout = 10000),
    opts_tooltip(
       css = "
       background-color:white;
       color:black;
       padding:5px;
       border-radius:5px;
       font-family:National;
       font-size:20px;",#
      #opacity = 0.9,
      use_fill = FALSE
      ),
    opts_sizing(rescale = TRUE),
    opts_zoom(max = 2)
  ))

pfn_fig_ggiraph_int
  
#saving the file
htmltools::save_html(pfn_fig_ggiraph_int, file.path(out_dir_int_tests, "pfn_fig_ggiraph.html"))```



Welcome to SO! While you did almost everything right in your first post, your code is still not reproducible, i.e. I get errors object 'temp_fc_pal' not found, object 'soc_year' not found, ... Please make sure other users can run your code, e.g. by checking that it works in a fresh R session. Also, please try to make your example code as minimal as possible, e.g. all the options you add to girafe are not necessary to show your issue.

This said: I think the issue is the same as the one in the referenced link. And from my understanding you are not doing anything wrong. This might be a bug or a missing feature. But rom my understanding a geom_line is simply treated as one object and hence only allows to have one tooltip for the line, not the single points or segments which make up the line. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78804642/hover-aesthetic-doesnt-work-in-ggiraphgirafe/78804693#78804693 for a recent and related question which offers the same workaround.

Sorry for my belated response - I missed these in my inbox. And thank you for the warm welcome and helpful reply! Noted on trimming down the code in future posts; I will do that. And got it. I'll use geom_point_interactive as a workaround.
